# I need to write a query to mark previous record as “Not eligible ” if a new record comes in within 30 days with same POS Order ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to write a query to retrieve the records which have POS_ORDER_ID in the table with same POS_ORDER_ID which comes within 30days as new record with status 'Canceled', 'Discontinued' and need to mark previous POS_ORDER_ID record as it as not eligible

Table columns:

POS_ORDER_ID,
Status,
Order_date,
Error_description

Comment: How do you identify if it is a old record or new record? Do you have any date column?

Comment: can you provide at least a data sample and an expected result based on it ?

Comment: @JimMacaulay order_date is a column which is used as reference to identify old and new

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I do not have sample data but can help you with an example scenario i.e., where in one record with POS_order_id is 112255 is available with order date as 07/01/2020 and within 30 days another new record with POS_Order_id 112255 comes with order_date 07/20/2020 then we must mark the POS_order_id which came on 07/01/2020 as 'Not eligible'

Comment: What does "mark" mean?  Does that mean return a status in a query?  Or does it mean to update the record?  How is "not eligible" represented?  I am voting to close.  You should ask a question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

A query containing `MAX()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic functions might help you such as  :

```
with t as
(
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by pos_order_id order by Order_date desc ) as rn,
       max(Order_date) over (partition by pos_order_id) as mx
  from tab t -- your original table
)
select pos_order_id, Status, Order_date, Error_description, 
       case when rn >1 
              and t.status in ('Canceled','Discontinued') 
              and mx - t.Order_date <= 30 
             then 
                'Not eligible' 
             end as "Extra Status"
  from t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1c32da190e8877f6a8ef9e72f2540cc7)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

Select and validate

```
select POS_ORDER_ID, Status, Order_date, Error_description, row_number() 
over(partition by POS_ORDER_ID order by Order_date desc)
from table_name;
```

Update query

```
merge into table_name t1
using
(select row_id, POS_ORDER_ID, Status, Order_date, Error_description, 
row_number() over(partition by POS_ORDER_ID order by Order_date desc) as rnk
from table_name) t2
on (t1.POS_ORDER_ID = t2.POS_ORDER_ID and t1.row_id = t2.row_id)
when matched then
update
set
case when t2.rnk = 1 then 'Canceled' else 'Not Eligible';
```